# I changed to Ubuntu, lost my files. How do I get them back?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, windows-xp, data-recovery, data-loss

So as you guys will probably know, the support for Windows XP will be removed. I decided to change to Ubuntu and I already love it! However, I have found a major issue, and have lost all of my original files from when I had XP. They are not inside any of the folders. I need these files back urgently, please help!

Comment: stop using your computer immediately.Then use some recovery tool.

Comment: Which recovery tool would you recommend?

Comment: I would say `ddrescue`. There are many, see [this](http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/20100226122928107/DataRecovery.html) for example

Comment: also read [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/286181/184942)

Answer (score 0):

What you meant by lost? Whether the partition still intact? If so you can use [active file recovery](http://www.partition-recovery.com/). If you formated the partition accidentally then you can try [active partition recovery](http://www.file-recovery.com/).

Sorry, I missed the point. You need it in Ubuntu right, you can install gddrescue and run ddrecue to recover the files. Please check this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery) for more details on ddrescue.